# Chrome extension sending message by clicking event from popup to background, then fetch data and return to popup. only one of the click events works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-runtime-messaging

I’m a student who has just started to learn javascript. I wrote an extension that can visualize the history data of the user.

So what I made was a Chrome extension sending message by clicking event from popup to background, then fetch data and return to popup. But I encountered some problem during the process of clicking event.

There are three different buttons that users can click, which can set the period of data to the corresponding time (”last hour”, “last 24 hours” and “last week”). I tested each click event individually. All of which works when alone. But when I put three buttons together, only one of them works.

I'm wondering why is that happening, and how should I fix that? Thank you very much.

I included here the part of code which isn't working

**popup.js**

```
//buttons that send mmesages
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    const lastHourbtn = document.getElementById('lastHour');
    lastHourbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('test 1');
        historyDiv.innerHTML = '';
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getLastHour' }, function (response) {
            generateVisual(response);
        });
    });
    const lastDaybtn = document.getElementById('last24Hours');
    lastDaybtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        historyDiv.innerHTML = '';
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getLast24Hour' }, function (response) {
            generateVisual(response);
        });
    });
    const lastWeekbtn = document.getElementById('lastWeek');
    lastWeekbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        historyDiv.innerHTML = '';
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getLastWeek' }, function (response) {
            generateVisual(response);
        });
    });

});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'getLastHour') {
      const thisHour = new Date().getTime() - ( 60 * 60 * 1000);
      chrome.history.search({ text: '', startTime: thisHour, maxResults: 1000 }, function (historyItems) {
          sendResponse({ historyItems });
    });
  }else if (request.action === 'getLast24Hour') {
    const today = new Date().getTime() - ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
    chrome.history.search({ text: '', startTime: today, maxResults: 1000 }, function (historyItems) {
        sendResponse({ historyItems });
  });
} else if (request.action === 'getLastWeek') {
  const thisWeek = new Date().getTime() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  chrome.history.search({ text: '', startTime: thisWeek, maxResults: 1000 }, function (historyItems) {
      sendResponse({ historyItems });
});
}
return true;
});
```

Comment: Debug it. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. BTW there's no need for messaging and the background script - simply use chrome.history inside the popup.